# How much weight/volume do microbes occupy within the human body?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology

Microorganisms constitute the bulk of all the biomass on Earth. I weighed myself yesterday, and wondered how much less I would weigh if I were completely free of bacteria and microbes, inside and out.

**Approximately how much weight and volume do microbes occupy within the average human body? How were these values obtained?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@AlanBoyd's calculations are reasonable, I think the estimate is off though.  The human microbome includes other bacteria which are not necessarily E.coli equivalent.

[The human microbome projects give estimates that microbes are 1-3% total body mass](http://www.nih.gov/news/health/jun2012/nhgri-13.htm).  i.e. several pounds of bacteria.

The GI tract alone has most of the microbome mass - [faeces is ~60% intestinal flora/fauna by dry weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_microbiome#Gut_flora), which for many adults alone must be hundreds of grams at any given moment.

Answer (score 6):

**The bacterial flora weighs approximately 90 g and, assuming bacterial cell density is approximately 1 g ml<sup>-1</sup>, occupies a volume of 90 ml.**

[The human body has 10<sup>13</sup> human cells and hosts 9x10<sup>13</sup> bacterial cells.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28numbers%29#1012)

[One *E. coli* cell has a mass of 0.95×10<sup>−15</sup> kg (wet weight).](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?&id=103905&ver=6)

Assuming that *E. coli* is typical with respect to mass of human microbial flora:

mass of bacterial cells in one human body = (0.95×10<sup>−15</sup> * 9x10<sup>13</sup>) kg
 = 0.0855 kg = 86 g

Comment: Just human intestines have over a kilogram of bacteria! A good enema will leave you 2kg lighter and that's mostly bacteria.

Comment: The number I read where more like 1-2 orders of magnitude more bacterial cells than cells in our body.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://www.gutmicrobiotaforhealth.com/en/about-gut-microbiota-info/), it's about 2 kg:

> Our gut microbiota contains tens of trillions of microorganisms,
>   including at least 1000 different species of known bacteria with more
>   than 3 million genes (150 times more than human genes). Microbiota
>   can, in total, weigh up to 2 kg. One third of our gut microbiota is
>   common to most people, while two thirds are specific to each one of
>   us. In other words, the microbiota in your intestine is like an
>   individual identity card.

Other [source](https://sciencetonnante.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combien-avons-nous-de-bacteries-dans-le-corps/), confirm it:

> Le chiffre a de quoi surprendre. Il s’explique par le fait que les
>   bactéries sont en général beaucoup plus petites que les cellules de
>   notre propre organisme. Il y en a donc une quantité énorme dans un
>   volume restreint; enfin sachez quand même que nous portons en moyenne
>   1 à 2 kilos de bactéries, pour la plupart localisées dans notre colon.
>   Il semblerait d’ailleurs que le colon humain soit l’un des écosystèmes
>   les plus denses que l’on connaisse.